# Ignis transaction not included in the blockchain

Tags: transaction-fees, ardor, ignis

The following transaction submitted to the Ardor blockchain remained unconfirmed and eventually expired, what is the the reason for this?

```
{
  "senderPublicKey": "...",
  "isBundled": false,
  "chain": 2,
  "signature": "3a49a35627b4ce8a5ac2822b35818f907aec4fd53e79fb02d900d88c0f991c0d71973c434ccaad318a1288a1fb64e53d20dc30de74beb18520c5f4bce06372d4",
  "feeNQT": "100000000",
  "requestProcessingTime": 0,
  "type": 0,
  "fullHash": "552ec333deb265d60ccfa4225123106ce4fc8f9a751185c561083b4cd9b14ed3",
  "version": 1,
  "fxtTransaction": "0",
  "phased": false,
  "ecBlockId": "18397966223991632613",
  "signatureHash": "72caad33596e08e67fe43f42033c0223f9abec9b440b10c07cfd186a037eb972",
  "attachment": {
    "version.OrdinaryPayment": 0
  },
  "senderRS": "...",
  "subtype": 0,
  "amountNQT": "77470950921",
  "sender": "12661870821659068934",
  "recipientRS": "ARDOR-LHJR-WZVF-VKTX-3PVAA",
  "recipient": "1451133144082759191",
  "ecBlockHeight": 384416,
  "deadline": 60,
  "timestamp": 22957813,
  "height": 2147483647
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you send a transaction to a new account on Ignis (i.e. ARDOR-LHJR-WZVF-VKTX-3PVAA is a new account) the fee you pay in IGNIS should cover the bundler cost of 1 ARDR. Currently the best bundling rate is 2.45 so you should have specified 2.45 IGNIS or higher as fee i.e. "feeNQT": "245000000". If you send it to an existing account the fee is only 0.01 ARDR paid in Ignis according to the best bundling rate.

My recommendation for exchange developers and application developers is to setup their own bundler as explained in section 5.3.4 and 5.3.5 of the [Ignis Integration Guide](https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/Exchange_Integration_Ignis)